# System Config Upload File Input Disabled

Tags: magento2, system.xml

Here is the content of the system.xml file:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="develodesign_productpagerendermsg" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">
            <label><![CDATA[Product Page Stock Location]]></label>
            <tab>catalog</tab>
            <resource>Develodesign_General::general</resource>
            <group id="company_flag" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1">
                <label>Company Display Settings</label>
                <field id="custom_message" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\File" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
                    <label>Identifier, SKU and Custom Message CSV Mapper</label>
                    <backend_model>Develodesign\General\Model\Config\Backend\FileUploader</backend_model>
                    <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">catalog/custom_message</upload_dir>
                    <comment>CSV Header must be set to Company Id, Product SKU, and Custom Message.</comment>
                </field>

                <field id="employee_mapper" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\File" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
                    <label>Employee Name, Sole Code and Boot Code CSV Mapper</label>
                    <backend_model>Develodesign\General\Model\Config\Backend\FileUploader</backend_model>
                    <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">catalog/company_employee</upload_dir>
                    <comment>CSV Header must be set to Employee Name,Sole Code and Boot Code. Allowed file types: csv, xls,text/csv</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="product_sku" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="4">
                    <label>Product SKU</label>
                    <validate>required-entry</validate>
                </field>
            </group>

        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

I am using a custom class ....`\General\Model\Config\Backend\FileUploader` that extends magento `Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File` Here is the file input greyed out in the admin frontend[image: greyed out file upload input]. Inspecting the element I can see a class 'disabled' being added to the input, removing this class sure fixes the issue, of course, I can add a js file to remove the attribute on document ready, however, I am more interested in why its disabled in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The backend model has to changed to below for files

> \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File

For images the backend model should be

> Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image

And for PDFs

> Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image\Pdf

Comment: I am using a custom class `Develodesign\General\Model\Config\Backend` than extends the `Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone sees this and had a similar issue, it was caused by the configuration value being locked with --lock-env on that environment